# @Async not working after upgrading to Spring Boot 1.3.3

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-boot

I have an application running under Spring Boot 1.2.3 that uses methods annotated with `@Async`.  To date it's been working properly.

After upgrading to Spring Boot 1.3.3, methods marked as `@Async` are not being called in a separate thread.

Here's a sample program that illustrates the issue:

App.java:

```
package test;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;


@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "test" })
@EnableAsync
public class App implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    @Autowired
    AsyncClass async;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        log.info("in run");
        async.start();
        log.info("done run");
    }

}
```

AsyncClass.java:

```
package test;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class AsyncClass {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncClass.class);

    @Async("myTaskExecutor")
    public void start() {
        log.info("in async task");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        log.info("done async task");
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor myTaskExecutor() {

        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor bean = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        bean.setCorePoolSize(1);
        bean.setMaxPoolSize(1);
        bean.setQueueCapacity(10);
        bean.setThreadPriority(1);
        bean.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        return bean;
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>dbush</groupId>
  <artifactId>async-test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>async-test</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>      
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <!-- this is the only line that differs -->
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Under 1.2.3, the log statements in the `start` method show them as running in thread `myTaskExecutor-1`.  Under 1.3.3, the same logs show that they run in thread `main`.

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need place your bean factory method in a other class annotated as @Configuration. Executor will be used for @Async method execution in this way.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig {
   @Bean(name = "myTaskExecutor")
   public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor myTaskExecutor() {
      return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Injecting into configuration classes might be a challenge, I wouldn't recommend it especially if that class is also an actual bean. IMHO your class does too much. Next to that move the configuration of the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` where it belongs.

Instead of autowiring create a `@Bean` method which returns a `CommandLineRunner` instead of you implementing it.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class App {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner runner(AsyncClass async) {

      return new CommandLineRunner() {
        public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
            log.info("in run");
            async.start();
            log.info("done run");
        }      
      };

    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {

        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor bean = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        bean.setCorePoolSize(1);
        bean.setMaxPoolSize(1);
        bean.setQueueCapacity(10);
        bean.setThreadPriority(1);
        bean.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

And of course cleanup your `AsyncClass`.

Comment: Thanks.  This setup would work in the simple example with a thread that initiates at startup, however the full program contains one of these as well as a second task that gets called via a web request, so putting the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor ` beans in their own separate `@Configuration` classes was the simplest solution.